# Using wrapInner on LI contents, but not child lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home

    <ol>
      <li>One
        <ol>
          <li>Beta</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to wrap the `LI` labels automatically in `span` tags, but just the labels, not the child `LI`s, like so:

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Home</span>

    <ol>
      <li><span>One</span>
        <ol>
          <li><span>Beta</span></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But after playing for a bit, I'm not sure if this will be possible. I was trying along these lines:

```js
$('.hierarchy li').wrapInner('<span />');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Home

    <ol>
      <li>One
        <ol>
          <li>Beta</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But then *everything* in the `LI`s get wrapped in the `<span>`. Is this possible to do, or is it something other than `wrapInner();` I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not doable using `.wrapInner()`, you can `.filter()` the `.childeNodes`, and wrap the `.textNodes`. Note that it assumes that all the matching `.nextNodes` should be wrapped with a span.

```
$('ul li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<span/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5WnJ4/

Comment: Works perfectly! It's going to take some research to understand what this is all doing! Thank you so much!